# How to use related select through jquery ajax and also through passing parameters

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the related select plugin for jquery mentioned http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-related-selects code: https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-related-selects

It works ok I have no problem with it. Lets say i use it on `example.php` page. Now what i want to do is to somehow prepopulate the selects when i open some link in following format.

```
example.php?stateID=so&countryID=coun
```

the passed parameter are the selected options for the menus. The StateID is dependant on CountryId selection and the former is populated after selection on countryID
Meaning that I dont have to do selection for menus if i have provide PHP parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way when there is get parameter in the url then on `document.ready()` call the `onchange event` of first select box and keep the country id selected for that select box

Comment: ok that will help to select the countryId, but what after that. how to auto load the states menu and select the stateID passes in parameter. A newbie here

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, thanks for putting me in right direction. I changed the value for `stateID` in the `onLoadingEnd` of the related selected.